# Find replace all strings expect ones that match regex

Tags: python, regex

i am currently converting all ' to a " using the following code:

```
    #Converts ' to "
    lines = []
    replacements = {"'":'"'}

    with open('netstat_data_IP_formatted.json') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
                line = line.replace(src, target)
            lines.append(line)
    with open('netstat_data_IP_formatted.json', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in lines:
            outfile.write(line)
```

and this is working fine, however i want to select all ports and remove all formatting around the ports, so would using a regex like this work and not pick up the IP addresses too ?,

```
^([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$
```

then how can i remove the formatting around the port numbers, or is there an easier way to how i am making this ?

So this is the input

```
{'l_port': '48856', 'r_host': '95.211.210.72', 'r_port': '443', 'state': 'ESTAB$
{'l_port': '443', 'r_host': '37.218.247.217', 'r_port': '35805', 'state': 'TIME$
{'l_port': '48662', 'r_host': '95.211.210.72', 'r_port': '443', 'state': 'ESTAB$
{'l_port': '51316', 'r_host': '91.194.90.103', 'r_port': '443', 'state': 'ESTAB$
```

this is how it is after the script run

```
{"l_port": "48698", "r_host": "95.211.210.72", "r_port": "443", "state": "ESTAB$
{"l_port": "40406", "r_host": "178.62.252.82", "r_port": "443", "state": "TIME_$
{"l_port": "443", "r_host": "60.191.48.203", "r_port": "58220", "state": "SYN_R$
{"l_port": "36058", "r_host": "37.252.185.87", "r_port": "443", 'state': 'TIME_$
```

This is how i want it

```
{"l_port": 48698, "r_host": "95.211.210.72", "r_port": 443, "state": "ESTAB$
{"l_port": 40406, "r_host": "178.62.252.82", "r_port": 443, "state": "TIME_$
{"l_port": 443, "r_host": "60.191.48.203", "r_port": 58220, "state": "SYN_R$
{"l_port": 36058, "r_host": "37.252.185.87", "r_port": 443, 'state': 'TIME_$
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your input file to see the actual formatting?

Comment: Find and Replace in a text editor might be easier.

Comment: Needs to be scripted, this runs every 30 seconds and feeds into another program, i have added examples

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to match digits with quotes but no periods:

```
re.sub("'([0-9]+)'",'\\1',line)
```

(Swap the quotes if you replace them first, of course.)

That said, if you need to do anything any more sophisticated you should be using the standard `json` package to actually parse the file and then format the data however you like.